# Is it possible to flag a User?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is it possible to flag a User, rather than just flagging all the spam answers that user posts?

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/18962/globalhunt

Comment: That would be really useful from time to time. If I remember correctly there's only a certain threshold on the amount of spam flags one may get before a user is blocked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Kind of, but not directly. You can't flag the *user*, but you can flag any (rather than all) of the user's posts with the **other (needs ♦ moderator attention)** reason and explain the situation. The mods can take it from there.

Answer (score 5):

If you encounter a user posting nothing but spam, and it's clear the user created that account simply for the purpose of posting spam and nonsense, it's best to flag as spam. Although, as Jim says, feel free to also flag a post as "other" if there really is something you need to describe in greater detail, but in general spam needs little explanation.

The Stack Exchange system is programmed to handle these types of flags differently than other flags. They stand out a lot more, and there are measures that Stack Exchange put in place to help prevent more spam from that same user.

When I see a post flagged as spam, I generally do some digging to see if the user has a pattern. Hope this helps!

Comment: It's fine. It would be better to be able to flag the user as a "Spammer", IMHO. But no worries.

Comment: You can flag the user with a custom flag but it won't come through as a high-priority flag (like spam does).  OTOH, as jmort said, if we get spam flags on a post we don't *just* delete that post; we also take a look at the user.  So either way the message gets to us.